# How can I get data from a websocket url [coincap.io] with PHP?

Tags: php, websocket, socket.io, serversocket

How can I get data from a websocket url [coincap.io] with PHP?

I am from Iran, `coincap.io` API is banned in my country.

For showing data price use with `wss://ws.coincap.io/prices?assets=ALL` (coincapmarkets wordpress Plugin)

How to get data from server and upload to another local websocket server?

**Can I get data with PHP from the server and change coincap.io websocket url to new address ?**